# How to reference an array and write to another array with more than one column per iteration

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, multidimensional-array

I am curious if I can copy multiple columns to a new array from an existing array in one iteration of a loop.  Suppose we have the following general example:

Array1 contains 10,000 elements in column1, 10,000 elements in column2, and 10,000 elements in column 3, etc.

Let's say that I want a new array generated off that information, only I want only columns 1 and 2 populated.  Can I do this by looping only once with a correctly dimensioned target array?  For instance:

```
'Assume TargetArray has already been ReDimmed to the size of Array1 in the code prior
For i=0 to UBound(Array1)
TargetArray(x,1)= Array1(x,1)
TargetArray(x,2)=Array1(x,2)
Next
```

So can this be done in one step, or do I have to make a loop for each dimension I want to add to the array.  Is there any speed savings by doing two operations per loop as stated above (assuming it works).

Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: Have you tried the code you posted here? It looks like it will work (or very nearly will) to my eyes. To answer your secondary question, yes. Of course looping through 10,000 items once is faster than looping through 10,000 items two or three times.

Comment: I have tried it.  This example will work, but I have noticed that I have some blank values in some of the dimensions, and it is causing weird results.  I just assumed that if I forced it to the size of the known complete column that the data would follow.  I was worried that my logic was at fault, and not the data. :)

Comment: I think it might be your data. Can you define "weird results"?

Comment: Expected rows of data flat out missing from the target array.  I don't have the code with me right now as this is a personal project (and I'm at work), but it has frustrated me for a few tries.  I have tried declaring them as variants and doubles, all to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just using Range objects? I just made 100 values in columns A and B, and copy them to F and G. Or are you trying to plug values from the first three columns into an equation to give you values for the new two columns?

```
Sub CopyRange()

Dim Array1 As Range
Dim Array2 As Range


Set Array1 = Range("A1:B100")
Set Array2 = Range("F1:G100")

Array2.Value = Array1.Value


End Sub
```

Comment: This isn't an array, it is a range object and is handled differently. The OP is asking how to translate a particular section of a 2-dimensional array into another 2-dimensional array, which is not what your answer sets out to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Your example should work as what RubberDuck commented.
It is similar in below example which works at my end.
I can't fit it to comments so I have no choice to post it as answer.

```
Dim TargetArray ' declared as Variant type, not array of variants

ReDim TargetArray(0 To Ubound(Array1, 0), 0 To 1) ' for 2 columns
For i = 0 To Ubound(Array1, 1)
    TargetArray(i, 0) = Array1(i, 0)
    TargetArray(i, 1) = Array1(i, 1)
Next
```

Is this close to what you have? If so, then that should work.